# Finding C++ interval tree algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, red-black-tree, interval-tree

I'm trying to find an efficient C++ interval tree implementation (mostly likely based on red black trees) without a viral or restrictive license. Any pointers to a clean lightweight standalone implementation? For the use case I have in mind, the set of intervals is known at the outset (there would be say a million) and I want to be able to quickly obtain a list of intervals that overlap a given interval. Thus the tree once built will not change -- just needs rapid queries.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a template-based interval tree implementation in C++, https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree.  MIT license.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library offers red/black trees `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::set` and `std::multiset`.

Really, I can't think of any way to handle this more efficiently than to keep a `std::map` of iterator pairs, and passing those iterator pairs to `upper_bound()` and `lower_bound()`.  You'd want the iterator pairs to be kept in a map themselves so that you could easily zero in on which pairs are likely to be in the interval (if the beginning iterator in the "candidate interval" comes after the end of the given interval you're looking at, then you can skip checking that -- and all later -- iterator pairs).

Comment: Could you explain this a little more on how map/set can be implemented as Interval Trees ?

Comment: @Kyuubi: I suggested implementing an interval tree with a `std::map`/`std::set` (that is, starting with `std::map`/`std::set` and ending with an interval tree; **NOT** starting with an interval tree and implementing a `std::map`, `std::set`).

Comment: @Kyuubi Going off of memory, I believe the idea was simply that you had (1) a collection of things, (2) a list of intervals in that collection that you were looking at, (3) you defined the intervals with `begin` and `end` iterators.  So, using a `std::map`, you could simply have the `begin` iterator be the key, and the corresponding `end` iterator be the value.  Using this, you can't find all intervals you want in one shot, but you can narrow down the intervals you need to filter through.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a C# implementation of Interval tree at [this link](http://code.google.com/p/intervaltree/). It's easy enough to translate to C++ for those in need