# Data structure for quick time interval look up

Tags: data-structures

I have a set of time intervals *In = (an, bn)*.  I need to run lots of look ups where I'm given a time *t* and need to quickly return the intervals that contain *t*, e.g., those intervals such that *an <= t <= bn*.

What is a good data structure or algorithm for this?

If it matters, in my case the *an* and *bn* are integers.

Comment: Java solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399821/data-structures-that-can-map-a-range-of-keys-to-a-value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) (which is a type of [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)).

These have logarithmic lookup time like other tree structures (e.g., RB trees), so you should see comparable performance to using something like a Java TreeMap or an STL map.

- [Code for Red-black trees and interval trees](http://web.mit.edu/%7Eemin/www.old/source_code/cpp_trees/index.html) from MIT
- There is a [C++ implementation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/last/doc_html/cgal_manual/SearchStructures/Chapter_main.html) in the [CGAL Library](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/last/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html).
- Here's a [C# Implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140412233406/https://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/RangeSearchTree.aspx)

Comment: There is a C++ implementation of an interval tree at http://www.mit.edu/~emin/source_code/cpp_trees/index.html, linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212808/help-finding-c-interval-tree-algorithm-implementation

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a space partitioning question. You have a large space with containers and a specific point in that space, what containers does it touch? A lot of games have to solve this problem, so it wouldn't be a bad idea to start there. Look for articles on "broad phase collision detection".

The simplest way to do this is to divide your number space into a constant number of pieces. Each piece knows which sets intersect with it, something that you calculate whenever a new set is added. Now, rather than testing every single set when you have a point, you only need to check the sets contained within the piece that the point is in.

Another general and efficient algorithm used is Binary Space Partioning. This algorithm subdivides your space into two sides. Each side would know which sets intersect with it. You can recursively repeat this process to your desired precision (although it doesn't make sense to ever create a subdivision smaller than the range of your smallest set).

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to check out the [C# implementation I've posted on CodePlex for IntervalTree](http://intervaltree.codeplex.com/) which solve this problem exactly.

Ido.

Comment: Thank you for the link. 
I know it's been a long time since this answer has been posted, so I apologize in advance for my comment and question.
By the time I have checked, one of the unit tests of this project does not pass: _TwoNonIntersectingIntervalsWithCommonIntervalThatIntersecBoth()_.
Because of this failed test, I wonder if the lib is reliable. Do you have any feedback about this lib?

Comment: Codeplex link is dead, similar Github link https://github.com/mbuchetics/RangeTree, Nuget package named RangeTree

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only one dimensional, so it's a bit simpler than the space partitioning problems found in most games.
You could have just a simple BST and in each leaf remember list of intervals to the left fromt the leaf.

if you had intervals A (0, 10) and B (5, 15), then the leaves of the tree would be (0 with empty list), (5 with A), (10 with A, B) and (15 with B).