# How do I store a Map in a Guava Cache

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, guava

I had a `Map<Range<Double>, String>` that checks where a particular `Double` value (score) is mapped to a `String` (level). The end users want to be able to dynamically change this mapping, in the long term we would like for there to be a web based `GUI` where they control this but for the short term they're happy for a file to be in `S3` and to editing that whenever a change is needed. I don't want to hit `S3` for each request and want to cache this as it doesn't change too frequently(Once a week or so). I don't want to have to make a code change and bounce my service either.

Here is what I have come up with -

```
public class Mapper() {
    private LoadingCache<Score, String> scoreToLevelCache;

public Mapper() {
    scoreToLevelCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(new CacheLoader<Score, String>() {
                public String load(Score score) {
                    Map<Range<Double>, String> scoreToLevelMap = readMappingFromS3(); //readMappingFromS3 omitted for brevity
                    for(Range<Double> key : scoreToLevelMap.keySet()) {
                        if(key.contains(score.getCount())) { return scoreToLevelMap.get(key); }
                    }
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The score couldn't be mapped to a level. Either the score passed in was incorrect or the mapping is incorrect");
                }
            }); 
}

public String getContentLevelForScore(Score Score) {
    try {
        return scoreToLevelCache.get(Score);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) { throw new InternalServerException(e); }
  } 
}
```

The obvious problem with this approach is in the `load` method when I do
`Map<Range<Double>, String> scoreToLevelMap = readMappingFromS3();`
For each key I'm loading the entire map over and over. This isn't a performance issue but it could become one when the size increases, in any case this is not an efficient approach.

I think that keeping this entire map in the cache would be better, but I'm not sure how to do that here. Can anyone help with this or suggest a more elegant way of achieving this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guava has a different mechanism for "a cache that only ever contains one value"; it's called [`Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration-com.google.common.base.Supplier-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

```
private Supplier<Map<Range<Double>, String> cachedMap = 
    Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
        new Supplier<Map<Range<Double>, String>() {
            public Map<Range<Double>, String> get() {
                return readMappingFromS3();
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

public String getContentLevelForScore(Score score) {
    Map<Range<Double>, String> scoreMap = cachedMap.get();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't see Suppliers here - https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained. Is there some secret place where I can find more of Guavas hidden gems.

Comment: @nikhil, don't forget to mark the question answered

Comment: Beware that this solution will [block](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v22.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#L225) multiple reader threads on expiration. Look in my answer how this can be avoided by using refreshing guava cache.

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix caching and business logic.
Unless your score mapping is huge AND you can load individual pieces, e.g. using readMappingFromS3(Double d) - simply cache the whole map.

```
    public static final String MAGIC_WORD = "oh please please give me my data!!!";
    private final LoadingCache<String, Map<Range<Double>, String>> scoreToLevelCache;


    public Mapper() {
        scoreToLevelCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Map<Range<Double>, String>>() {
                    public Map<Range<Double>, String> load(String score) {
                        return readMappingFromS3(); //readMappingFromS3 omitted for brevity
                    }
                });
    }

    public Map<Range<Double>, String> getScoreMap() {
        try {
            return scoreToLevelCache.get(MAGIC_WORD);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new InternalServerException(e);
        }
    }
```

Fetch level name like this

```
    public String findLevel(final Double score) {
        final Map<Range<Double>, String> scoreMap = getScoreMap();
        for (final Range<Double> key : scoreMap.keySet()) {
            if (key.contains(score)) {
                return scoreMap.get(key);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Plus 1 and Thanks, this is how I would have proceeded if David didn't tell me about Suppliers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that reads entire map at once and keeps [refreshing it asynchronouzly as needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751399/is-it-possible-to-configure-guava-cache-or-other-library-behaviour-to-be-if-t/) via [asyncReloading](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#asyncReloading-com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader-java.util.concurrent.Executor-).

It would return old value during [refresh](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh) without blocking multiple reader threads like `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration` [does](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v22.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#L225).

```
private static final Object DUMMY_KEY = new Object();
private static final LoadingCache<Object, Map<Range<Double>, String>> scoreToLevelCache = 
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(1)
        .refreshAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(CacheLoader.asyncReloading(
                new CacheLoader<Object, Map<Range<Double>, String>>() {
                    public Map<Range<Double>, String> load(Object key) {
                        return readMappingFromS3();
                    }
                },
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()));

public String getContentLevelForScore(Score score) {
    try {
        Map<Range<Double>, String> scoreMap = scoreToLevelCache.get(DUMMY_KEY);
        // traverse scoreMap ranges
        return level;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(e);
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Also consider replacing `Map<Range<Double>, String>` with [RangeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156669/603516)`<Double, String>` to perform effective ranged lookups.

Answer (score 0):

so far i couldn't find a way where you could dynamically store map value cached by guava, looks all values needs to be loaded once during initialization of cached map. while you requires to have a map loaded over time rather a solution is to use "PassiveExpiringMap" from org.apache.commons.collections4.map library

```
private static Map<String, String> cachedMap = new PassiveExpiringMap<>(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Which cache keys for given time as they got added to the map.