# Get the path "difference" between two directories

Tags: c++, directory, filesystems

**The situation:**

I got one or more absolute paths, e.g.:

1. /home/benjamin/test/
2. /home/benjamin/test/a/1
3. /home/benjamin/test/b/1

How can I get the difference between two paths? Let's say I want to know how I can get from path 1 to path 2. Expected result would be

/home/benjamin/test/a/1 - /home/benjamin/test/ = /a/1

Is there a more elegant way than subtracting the strings from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use `std::mismatch` ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/))

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
  pair<InputIterator1, InputIterator2>
    mismatch (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
              InputIterator2 first2 );

Return first position where two ranges differ
```

Compares the elements in the range `[first1,last1)` against those in the range beginning at `first2` sequentially, and returns where the first mismatch happens.

Some code:

```
string
mismatch_string( string const & a, string const & b ) {

    string::const_iterator longBegin, longEnd, shortBegin;

    if( a.length() >= b.length() ) {
        longBegin = a.begin();
        longEnd = a.end();
        shortBegin = b.begin();
    }
    else {
        longBegin = b.begin();
        longEnd = b.end();
        shortBegin = a.begin();
    }

    pair< string::const_iterator, string::const_iterator > mismatch_pair = 
        mismatch( longBegin, longEnd, shortBegin );

    return string(  mismatch_pair.first, longEnd );
}
```

A [full example with outpu](http://codepad.org/hLCtxWnv)t is uploaded at codepad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a call xxxx(...) way but since the file paths are trees, I would have thought a [tree traversal algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) would be as elegant as it gets...

There is stuff here in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212808/help-finding-c-interval-tree-algorithm-implementation).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple regular expression:

```
return($1) if longer =~ /^#{shorter}(.*)$/
```

Here is a [complete example in Ruby](http://codepad.org/aMxlIOld). You can test it out in command-line and start using it or this code can give you an idea how to write the regexp in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all paths into a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and see what suffixes remain.

A bit more general is using an [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), and retracing the steps for the minimal edit distance.

Both seem more elegant to me. However, what's wrong with subtracting the strings in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not worried about things like `/home/benjamin/test/c/..`, then this becomes a simple substring matching exercise.

The laziest way would be to use something like [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).  Alternatively, a little while loop that iterates over both strings until it reaches the end of one, or finds a character difference.