# How can I check if the values in a series are contained in any of the intervals defined the rows of a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I realize my title is a bit confusing, but I think I can make it clearer if we proceed by example.  What I want to do is a vectorized test to check if any of the values in a given series is contained in any of the intervals defined by a DataFrame object with a `start` and `stop` column.

Consider the series, `valid`, which is the column of a DataFrame called `trials`.  Here is what `trials` Looks like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 156 entries, 0 to 155
Data columns (total 3 columns):
start    156  non-null values
stop     156  non-null values
valid    156  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(2)
```

I have a separate DataFrame called 'blink`.  It has three columns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 41 entries, 0 to 40
Data columns (total 3 columns):
tstart    41  non-null values
tstop     41  non-null values
dur       41  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(2)
```

The last column is not directly relevant:  it's the duration of the eyeblik, i.e. the difference betwee `tstop` and `tstart`.

I would like to set each row of `trials['valid']` to `False` if the interval between it's corresponding `trials['start']` to `trials['stop']` overlaps with **any** of the `blink['tstart']` to `blink['tstop']` intervals.

I *could* iterate through the rows and use `np.arange` along with the `in` operator to do this in a nested loop, but it literally takes hours (my actual data set is much larger than this dummy example).  Is there a vectorized approach I could use?  If not, is there a faster iteration-based approach?

If anything is unclear, I'll of course be happy to provide additional details.

Comment: Would you mind providing some dummy examples that I can do some experiments for my solution before posting?

Comment: @waitingkuo.  Sure think.  Gimme a few minutes!

Comment: Cannot download your Trials data

Comment: @waitingkuo, fixed, sorry!

Comment: @waitingkuo, type shoudn't much matter.  What do you mean by "not match"?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat, these are biomedical data and therefore cannot be uploaded.  You'll also note that there's an accepted answer, so your downvote seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @blz Accepted, fixed the dead links in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blink data

```
In [27]: blink = pd.DataFrame(dict(tstart = [0,10], tstop = [5,15]))

In [28]: blink_s = blink.stack()

In [29]: blink_s.index = [ "%s_%s" % (v,i) for i, v in blink_s.index ]
```

Construct a series of of the blink (kind of like pivoting), but we need new names

```
In [37]: blink_s
Out[37]: 
tstart_0     0
tstop_0      5
tstart_1    10
tstop_1     15
```

The trial data

```
In [30]: trial = pd.DataFrame(dict(start = [3,7,12],stop=[4,10,16]))
```

Tile the blink_s across rows of the trial

```
In [32]: blink_df = pd.DataFrame([ blink_s for i in trial.index ])
```

Join em up

```
In [33]: x = trial.join(blink_df)

In [34]: x
Out[34]: 
   start  stop  tstart_0  tstop_0  tstart_1  tstop_1
0      3     4         0        5        10       15
1      7    10         0        5        10       15
2     12    16         0        5        10       15
```

Your answer is then a vectorized boolean expression (this maybe be a long one, so you should programatically generate it, but its not that complicated to do that)

```
In [35]: x['valid'] = ((x.start>x.tstart_0) & (x.stop<=x.tstop_0)) | ((x.start>x.tstart_1)&(x.stop<=x.tstop_1))

In [36]: x
Out[36]: 
   start  stop  tstart_0  tstop_0  tstart_1  tstop_1  valid
0      3     4         0        5        10       15   True
1      7    10         0        5        10       15  False
2     12    16         0        5        10       15  False
```

This will work if you want to have float data as your tstart/tstop criteria. If you restrict the intervals to only int data, then the solution is a bit simplier, as instead of doing all this, you can just create a single series of the values that are included (like blink_s), and just do `isin`.

In essence you are flattening the blink frame to a series that you then can apply to each of the trial

Using Isin (and OP data):

Convert to int64 data

```
trial = pd.load('trials.pickle').reindex(columns=['start','stop']).astype('int64')
blink = pd.load('blink.pickle').astype('int64')
```

Add in a row that we know is ni the range

```
trial = trial.append(pd.Series(dict(start=1000,stop=1200)),ignore_index=True)
```

Construct the range of values which we want to test

```
selections = []
for r in blink.iterrows():
    e = r[1]
    selections.extend(list(np.arange(e['tstart'],e['tstop'])))
selections = pd.Series(selections)
```

Return true if the passed start/stop are in the selection range

```
def f(s):
    return s.isin(selections).all()
trial['valid'] = trial.apply(f,axis=1)

trial[trial.valid]
```

I inserted 1 row that I knew would pass, no other rows pass

```
     start  stop valid
156   1000  1200  True
```

Comment: this looks great!  I just have one question though:  where are the values in your very first line coming from?  What's the [0, 10] and [5, 15] ?  Are those timepoints?  If so, doesn't that mean I can just replace them with corresponding the columns from my `trials` dataframe?

Comment: I just made them up! (this was before your example), ``blink = pd.DataFrame(dict(tstart = [0,10], tstop = [5,15]))`` I wasn't sure what your 'timepoints' looked like, and in particular if they are integer or not (my fist part of solution assumes they are float's, if you use isin they must be integers)

Comment: answer to your send question is, yes, this is exactly what you should do

Comment: thank you!  I'm getting a result which I'm 99% sure is erroneous.  Namely, the x['valid'] column is giving me entirely false values.  casting everything as an int is definitely an acceptable solution (rounding is preferable to truncating), but I'm having trouble seeing how I would go about doing that.  Would you mind showing me?  Also, [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5688105/) is my attempt at following your example.  Did I do something silly?

Comment: added an example using isin (and your data), none of your data passes; but I added a trial that does for testing

Answer (score 0):

Assume the size of `trials` is `m` and the size of `blink` is `n`.

First, sort the `blink` by `tstart` before you check each row in `trials`, merge the overlapped ones, it takes `O(n log n)`, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals)

While you check whether a start/stop pair is valid or not, follow the following algorithm.

1. Use the binary search to insert the start in the sorted `tstarts`
2. Use the binary search to insert the stop in the sorted `tstarts`
3. If there's any `tstart` between start and stop, return True
4. Find the the one just before the start, find its `tstop`, 
     if they overlap with the start/stop pair, return True
5. Return False

Above algorithm might help you reduce the time complexity to check whether a `start/stop` pair  overlaps with any pair in `blink` or not from `O(n)` to `O(log n)` where n is the length of `blink`

The time complexity will reduce from `O(mn)` to `O(m log n) + O(n log n)`. If `m >> log n` and `n` is large, that might help you a lot.