# How to speed up this object comparison algorithm?

Tags: performance, matlab, comparison, complexity-theory

Consider a matrix of dimension `Nx2`, where each row contains the lower and upper bound of a uniform PDF (i.e., probability density function).

I want to count the number of overlaps, where an overlap is defined as the condition in which two PDFs are overlapping, e.g.:

- PDF1: `[2,5]`
- PDF2: `[3,6]`
- The two PDFs are overlapping in the interval `[3,5]`.

Obviously, if three PDFs `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are overlapping, I count three overlaps: `p1` vs. `p2`, `p1` vs. `p3`, `p2` vs. `p3`.

I created the following MATLAB code that counts the overlaps:

```
for m = 1:N-1
    for k = m+1:N
        l1 = dataService.getObjectCoordinate(m,1);
        l2 = dataService.getObjectCoordinate(k,1);
        u1 = dataService.getObjectCoordinate(m,2);
        u2 = dataService.getObjectCoordinate(k,2);
        if (l1 <= l2 && l2 <= u1) || (l2 <= l1 && l1 <= u2)
            numOverlaps = numOverlaps + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

However, as you can imagine, this goes as `O(N^2)`, which is reeeeeally bad when `N` is big. I started the execution three hours ago with `N=10000` and it is still running.

May you suggest a way of reducing the complexity of the proposed algorithm, maybe excluding some of the comparisons a priori?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: The question I linked to has at least one answer that does it in O(N·logN).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yeah I just looked at that, and I am writing code to do it in less ... I think. We will see how this goes. So far what I have is running in under a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take back the comment I left earlier. You can definitely do this in a shorter amount of time. Based on the link provided by Rody and Shoelzer, you can use the following code to do this operation in under a second

```
tic
numIntervals = 10000;
ranges = sort(randi(100,[numIntervals,2]),2);
[vals,idx] = sort(ranges(:,1));
ranges = ranges(idx,:);
overlaps = false(numIntervals);
for i = 1:numIntervals
    temp = [ranges(:,1) <= ranges(i,2),ranges(:,1) >= ranges(i,1)];
    overlaps(:,i) = logical(all(temp,2));
end
overlaps = tril(overlaps,-1);
toc
```

`ranges` would  be an array of your interval start and end points.

The purpose of the lower triangle portion at the end is to remove any duplicate pairs. If `P1` overlaps `P2` then obviously `P2` will overlap `P1`. It will also remove the fact that `P1` overlaps itself by removing the diagonal

Do be very careful running this with large numbers, as the amount of storage it uses will very quickly fill up your RAM, depending on the amount you have. I tried keeping everything as a logical array to help in this, but it still adds up fast.

You could definitely remove the storage portion and save yourself a ton of time, but then you have to handle everything immediately in each loop.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is just O(N²) -- in each iteration you do 3N comparisons (don't forget the `all()`), and you loop N times. The fact that it runs fast is not because the algorithm is fast, it's because 10000 is not that big a number.

Comment: it probably is still O(n^2) it is just using the power of logical operators in MATLAB.

Comment: I realize that, but remember that big-O refers to the *algorithm* complexity; it is implicitly assumed that the best implementation possible in the language is used. So using the power of MATLAB operators *and* having an O(N·logN) algorithm makes execution times like the one you found also possible for much larger N -- your O(N²) will diverge much faster as N grows.

Comment: Of course, I understand that fact. I did not necessarily state anything about its complexity. But in terms of what the poster was asking, for 10000 intervals, this code will not take hours like the current implementation does.

Comment: True. I just took an academic interest in this problem :)

Comment: I completely understand. I tend to do the same but trying to implement the linked page's code quickly and easily was getting frustrating, so I figured ~10 lines in MATLAB was a good solution :)

Comment: Well, you have my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you profiled your code? A large part of the problem may be that you're calling `dataService.getObjectCoordinate()` four times per iteration. Instead, try getting all the data one time and store it in arrays before doing any comparisons.

After that, use the techniques described in answers to [Possible Interview Question: How to Find All Overlapping Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals).