# How to group sub-vector by intersect or not in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a 2d vector

```
vector<vector<double>> vec = { { 1, 0.5 },{ 2, 0.5 },{ 2.25, 0.5 },{ 2.6, 0.3 },
{3.3, 0.5 },{ 3, 0.5 },{ 3.1, 0.5 },{ 4, 0.6 } };
```

The first element is the start about a line. The second element is the length about the line. I can show it as follow graph
[image]

Now I want to get the group of the line index as they intersect or not. I mean I hope the result is

```
{{1},{2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8}}
```

If I'm in [Wolfram Mathematic](http://www.wolfram.com/), I can use follow code

```
list = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.5}, {2.25, 0.5}, {2.6, 0.3}, {3.3, 0.5}, {3, 
    0.5}, {3.1, 0.5}, {4, 0.6}};
g = RelationGraph[#[[2]] < #2[[2]] < #[[2]] + #[[3]] || #[[2]] < 
#2[[2]] + #2[[3]] < #[[2]] + #[[3]] &, 
  MapIndexed[Prepend[#, First[#2]] &, list]]
Map[First] /@ ConnectedComponents[g]
```

> [image]

But how to implement this in `C++`?

Comment: Use [Disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). (and record interval). Use [find-all-overlapping-intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals) to know which interval to join.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for your advice. I solve it eventually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this problem, what you basically need to do is group all the intervals together, that overlap or intersect directly or indirectly.

Let's assume that we converted `(start, len)` pairs to `(start, end)` pairs. So, now we have a list of `(start, end)`. If we **sort** this list by **start time** and iterate over it. Then:

1. if [image: eqn1]: means that the `ith` range is disjoint from any range uptil `i-1`. So, add it to a new group.
2. if [image: eqn2] : means that the `ith` range is overlapping/intersecting with some of the range(s) in `1..i-1`.

**Note**: [image: eqn3] is the max value of `end time` from `1` to `i-1`.

I've added rest of the explanation in the form of comments, in the code itself.

#### Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//a struct representing a range
struct range {
    double st, ed;
};

//just a shorthand :p
using prp = pair<range, int>;


/*
* Comparator that sorts by the start time of range.
* If start times are equal, then end time is used to sort.
*/
inline bool sort_by_start(const prp &a, const prp &b) {
    if (a.first.st == b.first.st) return a.first.ed  < b.first.ed;
    return a.first.st < b.first.st;
}

int main() {

    //your vector
    const vector<vector<double>> v2d = { { 1, 0.5 }, { 2, 0.5 }, { 2.25, 0.5 }, { 2.6, 0.3 },
        {3.3, 0.5 }, { 3, 0.5 }, { 3.1, 0.5 }, { 4, 0.6 }
    };

    //a vector of ranges
    //each element is pair of (range, position) where position is the
    //original index of range in v2d
    vector<prp> rng(v2d.size());

    //a vector of vector of ints that will hold the groups
    vector<vector<int>> idx;

    int i, j;
    //building ranges. end time = start time + length
    //position is stored, so that it can be used later.
    for (i = 0; i < (int) v2d.size(); ++i) {
        rng[i] = {{v2d[i][0], v2d[i][1] + v2d[i][0]}, i};
    }

    //sorting by start time
    sort(rng.begin(), rng.end(), sort_by_start);

    //starting of first group
    idx.push_back(vector<int>());
    idx.back().push_back(rng[0].second);
    double edv = rng[0].first.ed;

    for (i = 1; i < (int)rng.size(); ++i) {

        //if next start time is greater than the largest
        //end time encountered so far (maintained using edv)
        //it means the next group is starting, so push an empty vector
        if (edv < rng[i].first.st)
            idx.push_back(vector<int>());

        //edv maintains the largest end time encountered so far.
        edv = max(edv, rng[i].first.ed);
        //we want to push the current range into the last active group.
        //why last? because they are all sorted by start-time.
        idx.back().push_back(rng[i].second);
    }


    //displaying
    for (i = 0; i < (int)idx.size(); ++i) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < (int)idx[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << idx[i][j] + 1 << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Result:

```
1 
2 3 4 
6 7 5 
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Done!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> group_digit(vector<vector<int>> component)
{
    class interval_intersectionQ
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(vector<vector<int>> sub_group, vector<int> vec)
        {
            vector<int> continuous_line;
            for (vector<int> i : sub_group)
            {
                continuous_line.push_back(i[1]);
                continuous_line.push_back(i[1] + i[2]);
            }
            pair<vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>::iterator> interval = minmax_element(continuous_line.begin(), continuous_line.end());
            if (*interval.first <= vec[1] && vec[1] <= *interval.second || 
                *interval.first <= vec[1] + vec[2] && vec[1] + vec[2] <= *interval.second || 
                vec[1] <= *interval.first && *interval.first <= vec[1] + vec[2] || 
                vec[1] <= *interval.second && *interval.second <= vec[1] + vec[2])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    vector<vector<int>> origin = component;
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> group;
    while (!origin.empty())
    {
        group.push_back(vector<vector<int>>());
        group[group.size() - 1].push_back(origin[origin.size() - 1]);
        origin.pop_back();
        for (int i = 0; i < origin.size(); i++)
        {
            if (interval_intersectionQ()(group[group.size() - 1], origin[i]))
            {
                group[group.size() - 1].push_back(origin[i]);
                origin.erase(origin.begin() + i);
                i = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> one_digit(group.size());
    for (int i = 0; i<group.size(); i++)
    {
        for (vector<int> j : group[i])
        {
            one_digit[i].push_back(j[0]);
        }
    }
    return one_digit;
}


int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> origin = { { 1, 10, 5 },{ 2, 20, 5 },{ 3, 22, 5 },
    { 4, 26, 3 },{ 5, 33, 5 },{ 6, 30,5 },{ 7, 31, 5 },{ 8, 40, 6 } };
    vector<vector<int>> one_digit = group_digit(origin);
    for (vector<int> i : one_digit)
    {
        for (int j : i)
        {
            cout << j << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> 8
> 7  5  6
> 4  3  2
> 1
> ```